# Alarmmanager

Tags: android, java

Я регистрирую alarmmanager на 14 часов ежедневно, и если он будет повторно регистрировать, то просто обновит, а не добавит еще один alarm, но почему-то alarmManager  отрабатывает каждый раз при запуске этого метода, в BootReceiver поступает запрос сразу же после запуска этого метода в любое время.

```
public void notifyEveryDay(int hour){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BootReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(notifyEveryDay);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis() ,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо проверять (перед назначением времени календарю), прошло ли уже указанное время.

Т.е. назначаем календарю час, сравниваем кол-во миллисекунд в полученном календаре с текущим кол-вом миллисекунд, и если заданное время меньше, то прибавляем к нашему календарю 1 день. После этого назначаем календарь AlarmManager-у.

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ А как же Calendar.getinstance он же берет текущие данные, а я меняю только время, и если я неправ, как можно сделать так, чтобы она запускалась каждый день в одно время?

Comment: @eldqs, да, попутал, ща обновлю ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб получается, что надо каждый раз его обновлять вручную в bootreceiver  ловлю, если поймал, то надо будет обновлять время, каждый раз прибавляя один день? А нет ли способа, чтобы задать на ежедневное в одно и то же время.

Comment: @eldqs, ну так а в чём проблема? Подписывайтесь на событие запуска телефона, в ресивере этом запускаете ваш код с проверкой на время и всё.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб казалось бы можно проще сделать за раз! А что если смартфон будет перезагружен, нужно будет опять регестрировать?

Comment: @eldqs, ну так я же выше комментом написал... Надо один раз всего лишь зарегистрировать AlarmManager сразу после окончания загрузки телефона... И всё. Каждый раз при загрузке телефона оно будет регистрироваться... Неужели вы ожидаете, что однажды запущенный вами код навечно сохранится в памяти телефона и будет сам исполняться без явного к этому указания?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, я понял.